# Remove if unit only has one observation

Tags: r

I have a long form of clinical data that looks something like this:

```
patientid <- c(100,100,100,101,101,101,102,102,102,104,104,104)
outcome <- c(1,1,1,1,1,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)
time <- c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3)

Data <- data.frame(patientid=patientid, outcome=outcome, time=time)
```

A patient should be kept in the database only if they 2 or 3 observations (so patients that have complete data for 0 or only 1 time points should be thrown out. So for this example my desired result is this:

```
patientid <- c(100,100,100,101,101,101)
outcome <- c(1,1,1,1,1,NA)
time <- c(1,2,3,1,2,3)

Data <- data.frame(patientid=patientid, outcome=outcome, time=time)
```

Hence patients 102 and 104 are thrown out of the database because of they were missing the outcome variable in 2 or 3 of the time points.

Comment: Can you review the answers at your other questions, see whether there are additional questions you have about the solutions provided, and/or up-vote or accept appropriate answers? It should not be too difficult to figure this out using similar approaches to the solutions shared at [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65297927/1270695).

Answer (score 0):

We can create a logical expression on the `sum` of non-NA elements as a logical vector, grouped by 'patientid' to `filter` patientid's having more than one non-NA 'outcome'

```
library(dplyr)
Data %>%
     group_by(patientid) %>% 
     filter(sum(!is.na(outcome)) > 1) %>%
     ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
#  patientid outcome  time
#      <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>
#1       100       1     1
#2       100       1     2
#3       100       1     3
#4       101       1     1
#5       101       1     2
#6       101      NA     3
```

Answer (score 0):

A base R option using `subset` + `ave`

```
subset(
  Data,
  ave(!is.na(outcome), patientid, FUN = sum) > 1
)
```

giving

```
  patientid outcome time
1       100       1    1
2       100       1    2
3       100       1    3
4       101       1    1
5       101       1    2
6       101      NA    3
```

---

A `data.table` option

```
setDT(Data)[, Y := sum(!is.na(outcome)), patientid][Y > 1, ][, Y := NULL][]
```

or a simpler one (thank @akrun)

```
setDT(Data)[Data[, .I[sum(!is.na(outcome)) > 1], .(patientid)]$V1]
```

which gives

```
   patientid outcome time
1:       100       1    1
2:       100       1    2
3:       100       1    3
4:       101       1    1
5:       101       1    2
6:       101      NA    3
```

Comment: @akrun Could you help to review my `data.table` code in the answer? I am now learning `data.table` and I guess my answer could be improved

Comment: You can do `setDT(Data)[Data[, .I[sum(!is.na(outcome)) > 1], .(patientid)]$V1]` This would avoid creatning a new column 'Y' and then removing those.  By wrapping with `.I`, you get the row index as a column (by default, it would be named as 'V1'), which we extract (`$V1`) and pass as `i` for the `setDT(Data)` on the outer

Comment: Glad to know that you are learning data.table as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)
Data %>% 
  group_by(patientid) %>% 
  mutate(observation = sum(outcome, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%  # create new variable (observation) and count the observation per patient
  filter(observation >=2) %>% 
  ungroup
```

output:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 4
  patientid outcome  time observation
      <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>       <dbl>
1       100       1     1           3
2       100       1     2           3
3       100       1     3           3
4       101       1     1           2
5       101       1     2           2
6       101      NA     3           2
```